# Windows Forms chart and databinding

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I'm trying to create a databinding for a chart on Windows Forms. This is my code:

```
ch.Series["Dep"].Points.DataBindXY(data, "Date", data, "Value");
ch.DataBind();
```

Data is of type `DataBinding`. The issue is that whenever I modify the DataSource:

```
data.DataSource = ... (list)
```

The chart doesn't get updated. Actually this same approach works perfectly with widgets like comboboxes (as soon as I update `DataBinding.DataSource` the widget is updated).

I even tried calling `Update()` or `Refresh()` with no results. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call DataBind() at all. DataBindXY is what you want to do when you first bind it, and after you update the data source. For instance, this works:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<int> exes = new List<int> { 1, 3, 7, 9 };
        List<int> whys = new List<int> { 10, 20, 30, 40 };

        public Form1()
       {
            InitializeComponent();
            chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(exes, whys);
       }

       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
           exes.Add(13);
           whys.Add(50);
           chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(exes, whys);            
      }
   ...
```